# How a contract on Ropsten (deployed after fork) emit 3/5 events on the shorter chain while same contract on longer chain emits 5/5 of the events

Tags: events, ropsten, blockchain-fork

General info:

1. We have a full-node, which broadcast our txs.
2. We have a EventSource contract which contains 5 events types.
3. The eventSource contract deployed only after Istanbul fork. Our node was pointing to miners-chain so now it exists on both chains.

When I try to track Event 1 and 2 out of the 5 on the shorter, dev-chain I'm not able to find them on Ropten etherscan for example.

When I query them on the longer chain they appear.

How is that possible?

The event source is part of contracts complex and triggers as a result of multiple txs within the complex.

My assumption:
One of the contracts failed to be deployed on the shorter chain there for failing the tx there.

Why I think my assumption is wrong:
We have another deployment of that contract complex from before the fork.
But also there we're not able to fetch event 1,2 from the eventSource contract at all since the hard fork on Etherscan.

General information:
1. Part of the events are emitted well, from the two contracts complexes.
2. Rest of the app is still functional.

-----------------Edit-1--------------------------------------------------------

The contract code can be found on - [Github](https://github.com/2key/contracts/blob/develop/contracts/2key/singleton-contracts/TwoKeyEventSource.sol) and the deployed address is - 0xaee2bb51071df79284b87874e3b96a49cb0885de.

The following events:

1. AcquisitionCampaignCreated
2. DonationCampaignCreated

appears only on the longer chain and not on the Istanbul fork.

-----------------Edit-2--------------------------------------------------------
After we switched our full-node to shorter dev-chain and initiate the tx that suppose to trigger the campaign creation event it worked, now the dev-chain is also emitting that event the only difference that now we are no longer transacting in the longer miner-chain and only on the shorter dev-chain.

Comment: Can you provide links on explorer?

Comment: One of the changes introduced in Istanbul is re-pricing of some opcodes https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1679. That might have caused some transactions to fail if they have the gas hardcoded. Also we found sometimes light nodes are not  reliable because they can't connect to a full node.

Comment: @IvanZakharov Edited the post with more information.